# Correct key usage react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to extract the key from a received data, as indicated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). (check the Example: Correct Key Usage).
I have my code working, but when I try to imitate the correct usage approach to obtain the keys of the component separatedly, the data received from the call is undefined, which I don't understand.

This is the working code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ProjectSummary from './ProjectSummary'

const ProjectList = ({projects}) => {
  return (
    <div className="project-list section">
      { projects && projects.map(project => {
        return (
          <ProjectSummary project={project} key={project.id} />
        )
      })}  
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProjectList
```

This is my attempt:

```
import React from 'react'
import ProjectSummary from './projectSummary'

const ProjectList = ({projects}) => { //projects undefined here!
  return (
    <div className="project-list section">
      <ProjectListComponent projects={projects} />
    </div>
  )
}

function ProjectListComponent(projects) {
  let projectItems;
  if (projects) {
    projectItems = projects.map(project => {
      <ListItem key={project.id} value={project} />
    });
  }
  return(
    { projectItems }
  );
}

function ListItem(key, project) {
  return (
    <ProjectSummary project={project} key={key} />
  )
}

export default ProjectList
```

In the component top call `const ProjectList = ({projects}) => {` projects is undefined.
Apart from the correctness of the following logic, I expected that projects should be received with the info as in the working code. As I cannot handle the info in the code I cannot move on to obtain the keys separatedly as in the example.

Edit:

Find the code of the component that is passing the project to the projectList

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    // console.log(this.props)
    const { projects } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className= "dashboar container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 m6">
            <ProjectList projects={projects}/>
          </div>
          <div className="div col s12 m5 offset-m1">
            <Notifications/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit: find sandbox project [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wood-jtfbg)

Comment: who is passing projects to ProjectList ?

Comment: the dashboard component, find the code in the question edit

Comment: inside `Dashboard` did you check if your projects is defined there itself or not ?

Comment: no, but if you check the working code in the question, that is checked in the ProjectList component itself, so I was following that approach

Comment: Can you please try `console.log(this.props.projects)` or `console.log(projects)` and see if projects is defined in `Dashboard`?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay, can you post your on codesandbox or stackblitz?

Comment: thanks for your comment. It is undefined also :/. But how it can depend in the ProjectList component definition. It is what I dont understand

Comment: updated link in the question. I did not know sandbox etc. Hope that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the app:

[image]

You forgot to import `react` in the `Notification` and `ProjectSummary` components.

Also added conditional rendering in `ProjectListComponent` which was causing an error:

```
function ProjectListComponent({ projects }) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(projects));

  return (
    <>
      {/** */}
      {projects?.length &&
        projects.map((project) => (
          <ListItem key={project.id} project={project} />
        ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

The app is working now: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dew-is5ij?file=/src/components/projects/projectSummary.js:34-48)

---

Old Answer:

Pass props as an object to the component:

```
import React from "react";
import ProjectSummary from "./projectSummary";

const ProjectList = ({ projects }) => {
  //projects undefined here!
  console.log(JSON.stringify(projects));
  return (
    <div className="project-list section">
      <ProjectListComponent projects={projects} />
    </div>
  );
};

//--------------------------------
function ProjectListComponent({ projects }) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(projects));

  return (
    <>
      {projects.length &&
        projects.map(project => (
          <ListItem key={project.id} project={project} />
        ))}
    </>
  );
}

// //-------------------------
function ListItem({ project }) {
  return <ProjectSummary project={project} />;
}

export default ProjectList;
```

Working sample app: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e78flj?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i get this error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {projectItems}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: post it on codesandbox or stackblitz so that it will be easy to debug. Also, there is a bit of ambiguity about the shape of data that is being passed.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay, if you are getting the error `objects are valid react child`, then you are rendering an entire object. Try accessing the keys  inside the render calls

Comment: @rustyBucketBay, I have added a working app in the example in the answer, please do check out.

Comment: checkd that out and your project works, thanks a lot. However no tworking in mine. I think you can check that pasting the code in the sandbox project. Link in the updated question

Comment: Your have kept your firebase config details open! Be careful, and remove them if possible. Someone might end up misusing it.

Comment: updated answer fixed the app on codesandbox.

Comment: thank you very much. I was unaware that project was passed in many times as undefined until it is passed in with the filled in firestore values

Comment: on the other hand I am not familiar with sandbox. Could I have shared the app without sharing the firebase config file?

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226482/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-rustybucketbay).